# How to make image not to exceed certain width?

Tags: graphics

I've never used external images in my documents but today I had to look something up. I ran across `graphicx` but I wonder how to make all images not to exceed width of, say, 300 pixels by scaling them down (if necessary) to fit this constraint.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The `adjustbox` package has a `max width` key  and various similar keys. See §4.3 Minimum and Maximum Size, pp17-19 of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An automation that checks the width inside an `\hbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\xdef\maxwidth{0.9\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \savebox{\mybox}{%
    \hbox{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
\ifdim\wd\mybox>\maxwidth
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\maxwidth,keepaspectratio]{#2}%
\else
  \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image1.png}

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image2.png}

\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth]{image3.png}


\end{document}
```

PS: Not sure if recommended but you may try with different sizes and widths for image1,2 and 3 and check it.